# When I import my database into xampp local server it only imports 17 tables and I have 81 in my exported file

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to import my database into Xampp local server. I have created a new database (testingwc) in phpadmin, selected it and clicked Import then chose the file (testingwc.sql.zip) which is located in my C:\xampp\htdocs folder, and click Go. It gives me an error and asks me if I want to ignore, ignore all, or report it. I tried to copy the error #, but could not then it shows 17 tables in the testingwc database, but there should be 81.

I have performed the following supposedly solutions, but nothing yet.

1. I have changed the php.ini file to:

   max_execution_time = 1800 // equals to 30 minutes
   max_input_time = 1800 // equals to 30 minutes
   memory_limit = 2001M // equals to 2 GB
   upload_max_filesize = 2000M // equals to 2 GB
   post_max_size = 2001M // equals to 2 GB
2. Went to

   C:\xampp\mysql\bin

and entered

```
mysql -uroot -hlocalhost
```

and got this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -uroot -hlocalhost' at line 1

Is this enough information for anyone to help me or do I need to go back and try to import the database again to get the error?

Comment: When Have you entered this line mysql -uroot -hlocalhost ?

Comment: screenshot of errors https://ibb.co/pwxcpz1
https://ibb.co/ydZxgYR

Comment: I did if after I tried importing it and received error, so I dropped all the tables and then did the mysql -uroot -hlocalhost.

Comment: if you type mysql -uroot -hlocalhost while you are already connected , it's possible source of the error

Comment: Also, when I type in localhost:4433 this is what my screen looks like https://ibb.co/ctxVMYK

Comment: so I should stop apache and mysql and trying entering the mysql -uroot . . . ?

Comment: yes try this possibility

Comment: when i try this the command box comes up, but then automatically closes

Comment: after stopping mysql and apache, you need to restart them.This step was ok ?

Comment: yes and it has MariaDB [(none)]>